# using CsvProvider in F#

Tags: csv, io, f#, f#-data

I'm a beginner in F# and I'm trying to use CsvProvider and to reproduce the examples given here

http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

so inside F# interactive, I type

```
>type Stocks = CsvProvider<"MSFT.csv">;;

type Stocks = CsvProvider<...>

> let msft = CsvProvider<"MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;

val msft : CsvProvider<...>

> msft;;
val it : CsvProvider<...> =
  FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvFile`1[System.Tuple`1[System.String]]

    {Headers = Some [|"MSFT.csv"|];
 NumberOfColumns = 1;
 Quote = '"';
 Rows = seq [];
 Separators = ",";}

> let firstRow = msft.Rows |> Seq.head;;
System.ArgumentException: The input sequence was empty.
Parameter name: source
>    at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Head[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0044>.$FSI_0044.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

My understanding is that the CsvProvider creates a type based on a CSV file, which enables to read that file or a different file/stream with the same format later on. 
i think i have no directory problem, as the function would return an error if the file was in the wrong directory.
when msft is created, F# says the NumberOfColumns= 1 but thats obviously wrong.

This doesn't work either

```
> let msft = Stocks.Parse("MSFT.csv");;

val msft : CsvProvider<...>

> msft;;
val it : CsvProvider<...> =
  FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvFile`1[System.Tuple`1[System.String]]
    {Headers = Some [|"MSFT.csv"|];
     NumberOfColumns = 1;
     Quote = '"';
     Rows = seq [];
     Separators = ",";}
```

I am using the FSharp.Data library like this: (is it the good version ?)

```
>#r "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8\FSharp.Data.dll"
--> Referenced 'C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8\FSharp.Data.dll'
> open FSharp.Data;;
>
```

Please help !!! I've been trying for hours now ! thanks !!!

**EDIT**: the following is the whole log from F# interactive

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 14.0.23020.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> #r "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8\FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data;;

--> Referenced 'C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8\FSharp.Data.dll'

> open FSharp.Data;;
> #I "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I";;

--> Added 'C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I' to library include path

> let msft = CsvProvider<"MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;

val msft : CsvProvider<...>

> msft;;
val it : CsvProvider<...> =
  FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvFile`1[System.Tuple`1[System.String]]
    {Headers = Some [|"MSFT.csv"|];
     NumberOfColumns = 1;
     Quote = '"';
     Rows = seq [];
     Separators = ",";}
> let msft = CsvProvider<"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;

  let msft = CsvProvider<"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^

stdin(7,100): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'GetSample' is not defined
> let msft = CsvProvider<"MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;

val msft : CsvProvider<...>

> let msft = CsvProvider<"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;

  let msft = CsvProvider<"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^

stdin(9,100): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'GetSample' is not defined
>
```

Comment: what is the contents of the CSV file? (I suspect it is empty)

Comment: it is the same file that you can find on the http link that i put. its a 321ko file. Here is the first 2 lines Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2012-01-27,29.45,29.53,29.17,29.23,44187700,29.23
2012-01-26,29.61,29.70,29.40,29.50,49102800,29.50

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. When you downloaded the file, and if you're on Windows, did you make sure that you opened the file's properties and unblocked it? Files downloaded from the internet are often 'locked' for security reasons, and this may be affecting the CSV provider as well.

Comment: I'm on Windows indeed, but the file is not blocked. i have the same issues with other files as well. I can open them in wordpad without any problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that F# Interactive has a difficulty in finding the `MSFT.csv` file in the current directory. You can specify a full path relative to the current directory using a `Literal`:

```
let [<Literal>] Sample = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "\\MSFT.csv"
type Stocks = CsvProvider<Sample>
```

Then you can call `Stocks.GetSample()` to read the file.

This kind of error sometimes happens in F# Interactive, especially when you switch between files in different folders (I think F# Interactive remembers the folder of the last executed command, but I think it does not always behave as one would expect).

Comment: for clarity I have copy/pasted the whole session in F# interactive

Comment: When entering the full path, you need to escape the backslashes. You can write `CsvProvider< @"C:\foo.csv" >` or `CsvProvider<"C:\\foo.csv">`

Comment: `> let msft = CsvProvider<"C:\\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;

  let msft = CsvProvider<"C:\\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^

stdin(11,101): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'GetSample' is not defined`

Comment: `>   let msft = CsvProvider<@"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^

stdin(12,112): error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in quotation literal. Expected end of quotation or other token.`

Comment: You need a space before the `@` symbol - `CsvProvider<     @"...."     >`. This is a bit silly, but it is an artifact of how the F# parser works.

Comment: `> let msft = CsvProvider< @"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;

  let msft = CsvProvider< @"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\MSFT.csv">.GetSample();;
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^

stdin(18,102): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'GetSample' is not defined` I get more of the same. Perhaps the rest of the syntax is incorrect ?

Comment: NB: `let msft = Stocks.Load("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT")` and the following code from the url link works, when i compile code outside F# interactive

Comment: If you want to specify the sample inline, then I think you need some parentheses - you can try `(CsvProvider< @"...MSFT.csv">).GetSample()`. I always get this wrong, but it is nicer to used named type as in the original answer :)

Comment: @TomasPetricek I had the same problem for regular VS project.